# Best practice for a git repo for system config files (nginx/php.ini etc)

Tags: git

I have a fairly (I think) normal setup, on a CentOS 6 box.

My websites are in /var/www/sites.

- /var/www/sites/site1
- /var/www/sites/site2
- etc...

I have a git repo for each one inside each of those folders.

I'd like to create a git repo for various config files:

- /etc/nginx.conf
- /etc/nginx/sites-available/
- /etc/php.ini
- /etc/my.cnf
- etc...

I feel I could create a git repo in the /etc/ folder, have a .gitignore with a * wildcard to ignore all, and then force-add the specific files I'm interested in. Is that bad practice?  Feels a bit "dirty" somehow.

What if I decide there's an important file outside of /etc/ that I'd like though, maybe some config has ended up in /opt/ instead.  So maybe I should create a repo on /.  Hmm, starting to feel even dirtier, especially since this repo would then "contain" my website repos... even if they are excluded via the wildcard .gitignore - it just seems a bit... wrong.  Is it?

I guess an alternative would be to create a /config/ directory with a repo in it, move all of the relevant files to it and then add symlinks for where the files are expected to be.  No idea if that could cause unwanted complications/issues?

Presumably I'm not the first person to want a "config repo" - what do most people end up doing?

Thanks

Comment: Use Docker and commit your project-dependent config files in their repositories with where `dockerfile` also is.

Comment: OK, but if I don't want to use Docker?  I'm not saying it's not a good solution, but it feels a bit off-topic to my question and would probably just result in me spending days learning Docker and asking a torrent of extra questions...

Comment: I know my proposition is huge alternative to your approach - however learning docker is something about 1 day - trust me - it's worth it.

Comment: There is no "correct" answer to this question and that, unfortunately, makes it off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please see [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @KamilKiełczewski's comment, relying on Docker containers to isolate and setup a custom configuration for your server(s) is a good approach.

Otherwise, for a more traditional approach directly relying on configuring your host, you may want to try one of these three strategies:

1. Manage a single Git repository for your whole `/etc` folder using [etckeeper](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/);
2. Manage several Git repos for (parts of) your `/etc` folder using a custom configuration of [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh/) and optionaly [myrepos](https://myrepos.branchable.com/);
3. Or rely on GNU stow along with symlinks, using an approach similar to [that article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/26/manage-dotfiles-gnu-stow/)...

At first sight I'd say that choice 3 would be more difficult to maintain (because of the symlinks overhead), choice 1 would be OK if you just need to track all `/etc` files of a single server for backup purposes, and choice 2 would be the more promising approach (though I have not tested it myself in a concrete context).

Also, note that Git does not support file permissions as finely as it is required for most `/etc` files, but etckeeper has been specifically devised to refine Git on this aspect.

Comment: etckeeper looks great, that's the sort of thing I was hoping someone would point me at, thankyou!